# Java group a map by value where value is a List

Tags: java, group-by, hashmap, java-stream

I have a

```
Map<String,List<User>>map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("projectA",Arrays.asList(new User(1,"Bob"),new User(2,"John"),new User(3,"Mo")));
map.put("projectB",Arrays.asList(new User(2,"John"),new User(3,"Mo")));
map.put("projectC",Arrays.asList(new User(3,"Mo")));
```

Can use String instead of User.

String is a project Name but the same users can relate to different projects.

I would like to get sth like `Map<User, List<String>>` where
the key will represent a distinct user and a value as a list of projects' names to which he/she relates.

```
Bob  = [projectA]
John = [projectA, projectB]
Mo   = [projectA, projectB, projectC]
```

TQ in advance for any piece of advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the map's entries and the List inside of them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, List<User>> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("projectA", Arrays.asList(new User(1,"Bob"),new User(2,"John"),new User(3,"Mo")));
  map.put("projectB",Arrays.asList(new User(2,"John"),new User(3,"Mo")));
  map.put("projectC",Arrays.asList(new User(3,"Mo")));

  Map<User, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
  for(Map.Entry<String, List<User>> e:map.entrySet()) {
    for(User u:e.getValue()) {
      result.putIfAbsent(u, new ArrayList<>());
      result.get(u).add(e.getKey());
    }
  }
  System.out.println(result);
}
public static record User(int id, String name) {}
```

prints

```
{User[id=1, name=Bob]=[projectA], User[id=2, name=John]=[projectB, projectA], User[id=3, name=Mo]=[projectB, projectA, projectC]}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse this Map, you need to iterate over its entries and for each distinct user create an entry containing a list of projects as a value in the resulting Map.

## Java 8 computeIfAbsent()

This logic can be implemented using Java 8 methods [`Map.computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) and [`Map.forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

```
Map<String, List<User>> usersByProject = // initilizing the source map
Map<User, List<String>> projectsByUser = new HashMap<>();

usersByProject.forEach((project, users) ->
    users.forEach(user -> projectsByUser.computeIfAbsent(user, k -> new ArrayList<>())
         .add(project))
);
```

## Stream API

Stream-based implementation would require a bit more effort.

The core logic remains the same. But there's one important peculiarity: we would need to generate from each entry of the source Map a sequence of *new elements*, containing references to a particular user and a project.

To carry this data we would need an auxiliary type, and a [Java 16 record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) fits into this role very well. And quick and dirty alternative would be to use `Map.Entry`, but it's better to avoid resorting to this option because methods `getKey()`/`getValue()` are faceless, and it requires more effort to reason about the code. You can also define a regular `class` if you're using an earlier version of JDK.

```
public record UserProject(User user, String project) {}
```

That's how a stream-based solution might look like:

```
Map<String, List<User>> usersByProject = Map.of(
    "projectA", List.of(new User(1, "Bob"), new User(2, "John"), new User(3, "Mo")),
    "projectB", List.of(new User(2, "John"), new User(3, "Mo")),
    "projectC", List.of(new User(3, "Mo"))
);
    
Map<User, List<String>> projectByUsers = usersByProject.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().
        map(user -> new UserProject(user, entry.getKey()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        UserProject::user,
        Collectors.mapping(UserProject::project,
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
        
projectsByUser.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
User[id=1, name=Bob] -> [projectA]
User[id=2, name=John] -> [projectA, projectB]
User[id=3, name=Mo] -> [projectA, projectC, projectB]
```